# If a function $f$ is continuous $\implies$ $|f|$ is continuous.(Answered by Myself)

Tags: analysis, continuity

> $(i)$ Given a function $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define $|f|:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $|f|(x)=|f(x)|$ for $x \in E$ show if $f$ is continuous at $c \in E$ then so is $|f|$.
>
> $(ii)$ Now the converse is not true, find $f$ such that $|f|$ is continuous but $f$ is not.

Comment: IT looks good..

Comment: I think you could simplify your argument a lot: you need only check continuity where $f(x) = 0$.  Because if $f(x)$ is bounded away from zero, picking $0<\epsilon < |f(x)|$ allows you to use the same argument for continuity of $f$ and $|f|$ at $x$.

Comment: If you want us to check your solution, you can post the question and your answer in the body of your question and add the tag (proof-verification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(i)$ Now if $f$ is continuous at $c \in E$; 
$$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0 \ \ s.t \ \ |x-c|<\delta  \implies \ |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$
We want to show that if the above is true then the following is true also;
$$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0 \ \ s.t \ \ |x-c|<\delta  \implies \ ||f(x)|-|f(c)||<\epsilon$$
Now we look at the two terms $|f(x)-f(c)|$ and $||f(x)|-|f(c)||$ after testing with some numbers, you will see for all $f(x),f(c) \in \mathbb{R}$ $$||f(x)|-|f(c)|| \leq |f(x)-f(c)|$$. and so by using $f$'s continuity at $c$ we have,
$$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0 \ \ s.t \ \ |x-c|<\delta  \implies \ ||f(x)|-|f(c)|| \leq |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

$(ii)$ Define $g$ to be;
$$g(x) = \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \geq 0\\
       -1 & : x < 0
     \end{array}$$
This function$g$ is not continuous but $|g|$ is as it is constant.

Comment: You used reverse triangle inequality in "testing with some numbers".